# Associar uma controller a uma view já existente

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Normalmente, quando criamos uma `Controller` e associamos uma `View` a uma `Action`, clicamos com o direito em cima da Action e <kbd>Add View</kbd>. Aí ele cria a `View`, a pasta e etc.

Agora, e quando já existe uma `View`, e quero associar uma `Action` a essa `View`? Como eu faço isso? Com o direito não existe a opção <kbd>Add view</kbd> existente ou algo parecido. Como eu associo?

Answer (score 2):

Basta mudares o `return` da tua função, e colocar o nome da `view` que pretendes:

```cs
public ActionResult NomeFuncao()
{
    // código
    return PartialView("_NomeViewPartial");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir o retorno de uma Action pra a View desejada:

```cs
public ActionResult NomeAction(SeuModel seuModel)
{
    // Seu código aqui
    return View("SuaView", seuModel);
}
```

Além disso na sua `View` você também pode definir qual `Action` será chamada no <kbd>submit</kbd> do seu `<form>`:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("NomeAction", "NomeDoController", FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```